# Feedback on answer

Tags: support, moderators, down-votes, advice

On my answer here to this question: [is $0.\overline{99}$ the same as $\lim_{x \to 1} x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237571/is-0-overline99-the-same-as-lim-x-to-1-x/237575#237575) (yes it is a bit old) I was downvoted by a moderator. I am trying to understand what is wrong with my answer. Since a moderator downvoted me, I am taking it seriously.

1. How can I best get feedback on my answer?
2. If that would be here, then I would appreciate any such feedback so that I can improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment thread is already very long so [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) is probably the best place to discuss this.

Answer (score 8):

You got a downvote from a user who happens to be a moderator. Downvotes from moderators do not carry any extra weight: mods are not chosen for their mathematical prowess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it is fine to ask here on meta for feedback on answers?

Comment: I don't think so. Ask in a comment to the answer in question!

Comment: I tried that, but I didn't get a reason that I understood. I was thinking about suggesting that there could be a place for getting feedback on questions and answers. Sort of like a review.

Comment: The place to get feedback *is* there.

Comment: Actually, this would be true in an ideal world. If all moderators that were elected had the highest reputation between the candidates at the time; and if to some degree reputation correlates with mathematical prowess... you can make the final deduction. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: are you quite sure *I* had among the higher rep at the time? I thought my rep was (and is) quite low comparatively speaking.

Comment: @Willie: Are you sure, there weren't many contenders at that election. I suppose we can write a SQL query to verify that. But even if you're the exception, you're the only exception.

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, mine was definitely lower than Robin, Akhil, Qiaochu. Tim Wagner was close: his reputation on Dec 10, 2010 was ~3900. Mine was ~2600. `:-)` (No SQL required. Just a hand-held tabulator.)